# Display Salesforce calendar and schedule appointments on website

Tags: integration, website-integration

I work with a non-profit organization that offer medical appointment for their patients. Currently, the dates are introduced manually into Salesforce using the Events and Activities Objects, displaying them on the manager's calendar.

We need the patients to be able to schedule their own medical appointments through their website. The patient should be able to see what time slots are available and which aren't, in order to select only from those which are. Patients scheduling on the website are always new, so we should be able to create the contact record and the Event in Salesforce.

The current website has a form and a calendar, but neither is connected to Salesforce, so we face overlapping and non-confirmation problems. You may see the appointments site *[here](https://fundacionoiresvivir.org/citas/)*.

What is the most straight-forward way to address this requirement?

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Take a look at the Scheduler product: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-scheduler/get-started-with-lightning-scheduler

Comment: One of my colleague's orgs used [this product](https://sfdcpanther.com/full-calendar-js-in-lightning-web-component/). Terrific user interface

Answer (score 0):

If solution provided by @identigral doesn't work (as sometimes packages may not suit everybody), you can build custom integration.

Salesforce calendar events are stored in `Event` object. You could integrate with Salesforce using available [rest apis](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest.htm).

We built similar integration between Google and Sfdc calendars using these apis and it worked fine. Only issue we came across related to recurring events but don't think that is an issue in your usecase.